# Get a service based on the current model in ASP.NET MVC CORE filter

Tags: asp.net-core

I have the following ASP.NET Core filter:

```
public class ValidateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {

  public overrideTask OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next) {

     // get current model then if model is not null:
     // get IService<Model>

  }
}
```

How can I get the current model and request a service for that model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this

```
public class ValidateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var model = context.ActionArguments.Values.Where(v => !v.GetType().FullName.StartsWith("System.")).FirstOrDefault();
        //check if model is provided

        var service = context.HttpContext.ApplicationServices.GetService<IService<Model>>()

        //custom logic here

        return base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
    }
}
```

or

```
public class ValidateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly Type _modelType;

    public MyCustomValidationAttribute(Type modelType)
    {
        _modelType = modelType;
    }

    public override Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var model = context.ActionArguments.Where(a => a.Value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(_modelType))
                                           .Select(a => a.Value)
                                           .FirstOrDefault();

        //check if model is provided

        var service = context.HttpContext.ApplicationServices.GetService<IService<Model>>()

        //custom logic here

        return base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
    }
}
```

In this case you need to supply concrete or base type of model

`[Validate(typeof(Model))]`

Comment: I am not sure that the name is model ... I mean I cannot use context.ActionArguments["model"] as Model. I need to get all arguments because I plan to get a service that apply to each argument. Usually I have only one: Model model ... But can be more. I will do this for validation since this way I can use async